# @Autowired for generic types is not working when spring is upgraded from 3.2 to 4.2

Tags: spring, spring-4, spring-bean

I am upgrading spring from 3.2 to 4.2 in my jersey implemented RESTful web app in which spring is used as DI. I have below class hierarchy:

```
interface Representor<S> {...}

@Component
class MyRepresentor implements Representor<SomeType> {...}

class Foo implements SomeType {...}

class Bar implements SomeType {...}

@Component
MyResource {

  @Autowired
  private Representor<Foo> representor;
}
```

The line `private Representor<Foo> representor` gives me a compilation error `Could not autowire. No beans of 'Representator<Foo>' type found`. It used to work well with Spring 3.2

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myRepresentor")
  private Representor<Foo> representor;
```

also this:

```
 @Compenent
 interface Representor<S> {...}
```

both of them resolved compilation error but resulted in runtime error `No qualifying bean of type [a.b.Representor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by adding generic type to `MyRepresentor` class.

```
@Component
class MyRepresentor<T> implements Representor<SomeType> {...}
```

Answer (score -1):

Annotate your interface with @Component. Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. It resolved the compilation error but gives me a run time error `No qualifying bean of type [a.b.Representor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency`

Comment: Yes. It will not work if you don't annotate at least one implementation class as "@component" for that interface. It will give runtime error.